# configparser : which encoding on windows?

Tags: python, windows, encoding, configparser

My Python3 project works well on Linux but I got a problem with the *configparser* module on Windows. Every files of my own are encoded using UTF-8/unicode.

The following code :

```
    CONFIG_INI = configparser.ConfigParser()
    CONFIG_INI.read( "config.ini" )
```

raises an error when launched from cmd.exe :

```
    [..., from c:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 [...]
```

So, why does my program use the CP1252 encoding instead of the unicode one ? I can't see on the *configparser* [page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) how to set a specific encoding.

Any idea ? Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConfigParser with Unicode items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648517/configparser-with-unicode-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ConfigParser with Unicode items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648517/configparser-with-unicode-items) they offer:

```
cfg.readfp(codecs.open("myconfig", "r", "utf8"))
```

Have you tried that?
Cheers!

Comment: It works ! But I don't understand why my program uses, on Windows, the cp1252 encoding to read a file ... ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the link.